# Allow Button Submit on Click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have an web page that has a submit button. My submit button looks like the following:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary wait-on-click">
  <span>Submit</span>
</button>
```

When a user clicks the submit button, I want to disable the button and let the user know that something is happening. To do that, I have the following JavaScript:

```
$('.wait-on-click').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  $('span', this).text('Please wait...');
});
```

The button disables. The text is updated. However, the submit does not actually get submitted to the server. If I comment out the body of my JavaScript function, it works fine. I do not understand how to fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: @AmmarCSE's answer is correct, `preventDefault` is preventing the form from submitting. But if you allow the form to submit, all your messing with the button is pointless, because when the form posts, your changes will be gone. For your code to make sense, you would need to submit your form using Ajax. Is that the case?

Comment: I found your real problem after testing. See my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is with this line

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

This is preventing the default behavior of the submit button, i.e., **submitting**! Therefore, remove it.

**Update**

After testing, I have found the problem.
I believe your problem is with this line

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

For some reason, this is preventing the form from submitting. Therefore, put it in the submit handler.

```js
$('.wait-on-click').click(function(e) {
  $('span', this).text('Please wait...');
});

$('form').on('submit', function() {
  $('.wait-on-click').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="n" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary wait-on-click">
    <span>Submit</span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I had already tried that. Unfortunately, that is not the issue. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: @ZachTempleton, can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: That works! It was the submit piece that was the killer. Thank you for your help!